# How can I move /var/log to a btrfs subvolume? (ubuntu 15.04 desktop)

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, opensuse, btrfs

I'm trying to move /var/log/. to its own subvolume.  I've tried a number of things, but the /etc/fstab entry never does what I'd hope.  My examples here use `/spam` because I don't want to trash the log files while I work this out.  My questions are in **bold** below.

I won't bore you with what won't work. But here's where I'm at:

```
thor / 158# btrfs subvolume create /spam
Create subvolume '//spam'
thor / 161# ll -d spam
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 25 16:19 spam/
thor / 163# df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   1540072       0   1540072   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       310140    5380    304760   2% /run
/dev/sdb1      btrfs     33739776 7791536  24482480  25% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      1550684     156   1550528   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      1550684       0   1550684   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      btrfs     33739776 7791536  24482480  25% /home
cgmfs          tmpfs          100       0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs          tmpfs       310140      44    310096   1% /run/user/1000


thor / 164# btrfs subvolume list /
ID 257 gen 289 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 286 top level 5 path @home
ID 263 gen 41 top level 257 path var/lib/machines
ID 275 gen 287 top level 257 path spam
thor / 165#  grep -v '^#' /etc/fstab
UUID=ee321c37-2ccc-4016-aa0b-9cf9280be11e /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
UUID=ee321c37-2ccc-4016-aa0b-9cf9280be11e /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID=aff22fd4-48d6-4c8c-9c2e-260c05028fba none            swap    sw              0       0
thor / 166#
```

My OpenSUSE machine (hence the different UUID) mounts a bunch of subvolumes from the `fstab` with entries such as:

```
UUID=2c2aa4ed-bb4e-4c44-b222-4e75dc0469f2 /spam btrfs subvol=spam 0 0
```

If I try this on my Ubuntu machine, it won't boot.  An `strace` from single user mode show that `mount(2)` fails with:

```
mount("/dev/sdb1", "/spam", "btrfs", MS_MGC_VAL, "subvol=spam") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Furthermore, if I df the directory, I get this:

```
thor /spam 174# df -T /spam/.
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
-              -     33739776 7791776  24482368  25% /spam
thor /spam 175#
```

**My first question: What am I missing?**  Something's wrong because it's mis-behaving.
**Second question: Am I posting in the right place?**
Thanks!

**Update 1:**

```
thor /spam 175# uname -a
Linux thor 3.19.0-23-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 7 18:52:29 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My first question: What am I missing?** Something's wrong because it's mis-behaving.

Currently, the path of your `spam` subvolume with respect to the btrfs root is `@/spam` because the `spam` subvolume was created within the `@` subvolume. Use `btrfs sub list -a /` to see this. You will need `subvol=@/spam` in `fstab` to mount it.

But I think you actually want to create the subvolume in the btrfs root itself, in which case you will need to mount the root somewhere to create the subvolume:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/tmp/
mount -o subvol=/ /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp/
btrfs sub create /mnt/tmp/spam/
```

> **Second question: Am I posting in the right place?**

I suggest the [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this.

Comment: Awesome!  And I'll post future questions to Unix/Linux Stack Exchange.